# How to get the correct number of bytes sent and received in TrafficStats?

Tags: android, traffic, network-traffic, traffic-measurement

My app is trying to count the number of bytes send and received over WiFi/LAN and mobile data connections. To do that, I get the values of `TrafficStats` counters at one point in time and subtract that from its values the next time I check.

```
// get current values of counters
long currentMobileTxBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
long currentMobileRxBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
long totalTxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
long totalRxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();

// to get mobile data count, subtract old from current
long currentMobileSent = currentMobileTxBytes - oldMobileTxBytes;
long currentMobileReceived = currentMobileRxBytes - oldMobileRxBytes;

// to get WiFi/LAN data count, subtract total from mobile
long currentNetworkSent = totalTxBytes - currentMobileTxBytes;
long currentNetworkReceived = totalRxBytes - currentMobileRxBytes;
```

I feel that the above algorithm is reasonable, however, I'm not sure how to check the accuracy of these counters. For example, when I tried uploading a 2.7MB file to Dropbox via WiFi, the `currentMobileSent` value I got was around 10MB. And even without surfing the web until the next check, I get non-zero values indicating that I did receive some bytes of data over the waiting period.

Is there a way for me to check how `TrafficStats` arrives at these numbers? I'm aware that besides my browser, there might be other applications running in the background that connect to the internet, but 2.7MB to 10MB just seems like a huge jump--I even "received" 90MB once without doing anything. Or is there something wrong with the way I'm computing the bytes sent and received?

Comment: TrafficStats is including the overhead of TCP/IP packet headers. They are *physically* the total bytes transmitted. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26519333/365102)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/):

1. Create a new Android project in Eclipse. Remember to use the TrafficStats class you must target the API for Android 2.2 (Froyo) or
   higher.
2. In the `/res/layout` folder we will create a activity_main.xml resource. For this project, we are just using a series of text views in a vertically
   stacked linear layout.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:paddingBottom="20dip"
       android:text="Traffic Stats Demo"
       android:textSize="16sp"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="Transmit Bytes"
       android:textColor="#00ff00"
       android:textSize="14sp" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/TX"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="0"
       android:textSize="14sp" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="Receive Bytes"
       android:textColor="#ff0000"
       android:textSize="14sp" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/RX"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="0"
       android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

With our layout in place we can move on to the /src folder. Create
MainActivity.java by extending the Activity/AppCompatActivity class. Let’s also go ahead and
declare three private class variables.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.authorwjf;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.net.TrafficStats;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private long mStartRX = 0;
    private long mStartTX = 0;
}
```

We will use the on create override to initialize our private
variables, as well as schedule a callback on the UI thread. Make a
note of the check for the enum TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED. While my
experience with the TrafficStats class has been without a hitch, the
official Google documentation states that some devices may not support
this type of reporting and when that is the case the call returns the
aforementioned value. For that reason it’s a good idea to write your
code defensively, as I’ve demonstrated here.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
    mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();

    if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
        alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
        alert.show();
    } else {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
}
```

Last but not least we need to update our display and reschedule the
runnable.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        TextView RX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RX);
        TextView TX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TX);
        long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mStartRX;
        RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
        long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - mStartTX;
        TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and come back to your answer if it really works more accurately.

Comment: This only checks for the number of bytes used whatever the connection, right? I need to discriminate between mobile data (3G, 4G) usage, and regular WiFi/LAN usage. In any case, your approach seems to be similar to mine and perhaps validates that my current algorithm is right.

Comment: I guess this is as close as I'll get to an answer.

Comment: yeah you just have to do some substraction with oldbytes to get the new updated value as you said

Comment: **IN ADDITION TO ANSWER:** The counters for mobile data seem accurate, while the computed WiFi/LAN data always seem too large. We really don't know what that difference between the total and mobile means and I'm simply assuming that it's WiFi/LAN consumption. There's got to be a reason why Google didn't instead write a separate method that simply returned the WiFi/LAN measurements, like how there are separate counters for mobile data.

Comment: @Tom, Mr.Tom he has accepted the answer that means this answer was useful for him.

Comment: @Ramesh Sorry, I meant to add a comment explaining my downvote.  I had two issues - first I interpreted his Q as being about stats for his app, but now I think I was wrong (so I've removed the downvote).  But also, I've seen that there are lots of bugs and issues with these API's - hence his comment (2 up) perhaps.  Enough issues, in fact, that I think it wise to warn people about TrafficStats. (whoops it won't let me remove my downvote - sorry).

Comment: Attribution is required when quoting content that is not your own. I'm not deleting your answer immediately as it's the only answer to the question, but if you willfully remove the attribution link again, thereby refusing to acknowledge your source, I will remove your answer.

Comment: I sucessfully get wifi data but unable to get accurate mobile data can u help

Comment: Does TrafficStats give me installed application vice data? For example my youtube get 20MB, Facebook get 10MB. same as Mobile setting->apps->facebook?

Comment: @Matthew Quiros, "WiFi/LAN data always seem too large", did you found the right way to get the accurate WiFi/LAN data?