# Current Download/Upload Speed in Android

Tags: android, statistics, traffic, traffic-measurement

All,

I am newbie in android, just developing app to display the current Download/Upload Speed. I have got some tips from this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765562/how-to-get-the-correct-number-of-bytes-sent-and-received-in-trafficstats/12766067#12766067). It uses TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() function that returns the total Bytes received after boot and increases monotonically.

So i used the below code, to display only the Current Available Speed. But i am not getting the result. it displays the Total Tx/Rx values only.

1. Is there any Alternative to achieve this? Any Code snippets would be much appreciated as i am a complete beginner.
2. Also, i cant understand below code. Can some one explain this?

   ```
   private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable()
   ```
3. i need to refresh the data displayed in textView for every one second. I Guess

   ```
     mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000) ( );
   ```

   is used to do that. is there any alternative? if not, how does would be the control flow when using PostDelayed function? (I am bit confused)

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
   private long mStartRX =0;
   private long mStartTX = 0;
   private static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

   }
   private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() 
   {

         public void run() 
         {

           long TxResult=0;
           long RxResult=0;
           long or1=0,or2=0;

           long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX-or1; 

           if (rxBytes<1024)
           {
               RxResult=0;

           }
          else if (rxBytes>1024)
          {
              // RxResult=0;
              RxResult=RxResult+(rxBytes/1024);
          }
          TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rxOut);
          //mStartRX=rxBytes;
          TextView TX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txOut);
          RX.setText(Long.toString(RxResult));
          long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX-or2;
          if (txBytes<1024)
          {
              TxResult=0;
          }
          else if (txBytes>1024)
          {
              TxResult=0;
              TxResult=TxResult+(txBytes/1024);
          }

          TX.setText(Long.toString(TxResult));
          or2=or2+txBytes;
           or1=or1+rxBytes;
           mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 100);

          }
    };
   ```

Comment: Because i will not solve the first problem i will put it here instead. the piece of code is just creating a Thread object which contains the code you want to execute, and you assign it to the handler that will execute it every second. you can search more about threads on google and you can find a more in-depth answer for that.

Comment: Try this code 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193518/how-to-measure-upload-download-speed-and-latency-in-android-wifi-connection